# SharePoint Online Integration Compatibility

Tags: integration, sharepoint-online, csom

My application is running on dot net 3.5 framework and i want to integrate the SharePoint online from 3.5 framework application so it is possible to integrate that ?

Because the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client Assembly is available in 4.0 on wards so is there any way to connect the sharepoint online from my application which is running in 3.5 framework can't convert application to 4.0 straight away because it's a big application and i want to implement sharepoin online with this application.

I have googled and found two possible solution as mentioned below:

Make a new project and Compile it into 4.0 with COM compatibility which does not seems an good idea because it required to add the manifest file from all the invoked function which is not feasible for me.

So i am looking for a easy solution to integrate the 4.0 dll into 3.5 without com or is there any way to use CSOM libraries into 4.0 ?

I am looking forward for forum response. thanks in advance :)